# how can I access and print as HTML json items returned from an API call?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have the following json after an API call and I would like to be able to access all parts of it on my HTML page. I am sorry it is long, the json returned is:

{"api_id":"eb274c58-50ee-11e4-bd8a-12313f016a39","country":"United Kingdom","country_code":44,"country_iso":"GB","message":{"inbound":{"rate":"0.00000"},"outbound":{"rate":"0.03680"},"outbound_networks_list":[{"group_name":"United Kingdom-3","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":" United Kingdom-Landline","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":"United Kingdom-O2","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":"United Kingdom-Orange","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":"United Kingdom - Other Networks","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":"United Kingdom-T-Mobile","rate":"0.03680"},{"group_name":"United Kingdom-Vodafone","rate":"0.03680"}]},"phone_numbers":{"local":{"rate":"0.80000"},"tollfree":{"rate":"1.40000"}},"voice":{"inbound":{"ip":{"rate":"0.00300"},"local":{"rate":"0.00500"},"tollfree":{"rate":"0.05000"}},"outbound":{"ip":{"rate":"0.00300"},"local":{"rate":"0.01020"},"rates":[{"prefix":["44","44203","44207","44208"],"rate":"0.01020"},{"prefix":["443","44551107","4455114","445516","44555500","4455551","4455553","4455554","4455555","44558866","4455888","4456"],"rate":"0.01700"},{"prefix":["4470000","4470004","4470005","4470006","4470007","4470020","4470022","4470023","4470024","4470025","4470027","4470028","4470029","4470740","4470741","4470742","447106","447107","447400","447401","447402","447403","447407","447409","447410","447411","447412","447413","447414","447415","447416","4474170","447419","447420","447421","447422","447423","447425","447426","447427","447428","447429","447430","447431","447432","447433","447434","447435","447436","447437","447442","447443","447444","447445","447446","447447","447449","447450","447453","447454","447455","447456","447460","447461","447462","447463","447467","447468","447469","447470","447471","447472","447473","447474","447475","447476","447477","447478","447479","447480","447481","447482","447500","447501","447502","447503","447504","447505","447506","447507","447508","44751","447521","447522","447523","447525","447526","447527","447528","447529","447530","447531","447532","447533","447534","447535","447536","4475374","447538","447539","44754","447550","447551","447552","447553","447554","447555","447556","447557","44756","447570","447572","447573","447574","447575","447576","447577","447578","447579","447580","447581","447582","447583","447584","447585","447586","447587","447588","44759","447701","447702","447703","447704","447705","447706","447707","447708","447709","447710","447711","447712","447713","447714","447715","447716","447717","447718","447719","447720","447721","447722","447723","447724","447725","447726","447727","447728","447729","447730","447731","447732","447733","447734","447735","447736","447737","447738","447739","447740","447741","447742","447743","447745","447746","447747","447748","447749","447750","447751","447752","447753","447754","447756","447757","447758","447759","447760","447761","447762","447763","447764","447765","447766","447767","447768","447769","447770","447771","447772","447773","447774","447775","447776","447778","447779","447780","447782","447783","447784","447785","447786","447787","447788","447789","447790","447791","447792","447793","447794","447795","447796","447798","447799","447800","447801","447802","447803","447804","447805","447806","447807","447808","447809","447810","447811","447812","447813","447814","447815","447816","447817","447818","447819","447820","447821","447823","447824","447825","447826","447827","447828","447830","447831","447832","447833","447834","447835","447836","447837","447838","447840","447841","447842","447843","447844","447845","447846","447847","447848","447849","447850","447851","447852","447853","447854","447855","447856","447857","447858","447859","447860","447861","447862","447863","4478640","4478641","4478642","4478643","4478645","4478646","4478647","4478648","4478649","447865","447866","447867","447868","447869","447870","447871","4478720","4478721","4478723","4478724","4478725","4478726","4478728","4478729","4478731","4478732","4478733","4478734","4478735","4478736","4478737","4478738","4478739","4478740","4478741","4478742","4478743","4478746","4478747","4478748","4478749","447875","447876","447877","447878","447879","447880","447881","447882","447883","447884","447885","447886","447887","447888","447889","447890","447891","4478923","4478924","4478926","4478927","4478928","4478929","4478932","4478934","4478935","4478936","4478937","447894","447895","447896","447897","447898","447899","447900","447901","447902","447903","447904","447905","447906","447907","447908","447909","447910","447912","447913","447914","447915","447916","447917","447918","447919","447920","447921","447922","447923","447925","447926","447927","447928","447929","447930","447931","447932","447933","447934","447935","447936","447938","447939","447940","447941","447942","447943","447944","447945","447946","447947","447948","447949","447950","447951","447952","447953","447954","447955","447956","447957","447958","447959","447960","447961","447962","447963","447964","447965","447966","447967","447968","447969","447970","447971","447972","447973","447974","447975","447976","447977","447979","447980","447981","447982","447983","447984","447985","447986","447987","447988","447989","447990","447999"],"rate":"0.02650"},{"prefix":["44843","44844","44845"],"rate":"0.16520"},{"prefix":["44870"],"rate":"0.22350"},{"prefix":["44871","44872","44873"],"rate":"0.32010"},{"prefix":["4478360","4478361","4478369"],"rate":"0.40880"},{"prefix":["447"],"rate":"0.42870"},{"prefix":["4470"],"rate":"0.44030"}],"tollfree":{"rate":null}}}}

my getJSON code is:

```
$.getJSON("/get_pricing_data?iso="+iso, function(data) {
     $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
     var txt = '<tr>';
        txt += '<td>country: '+this["country"]+'</td>';
        txt += '</tr><tr>';
        txt += '<td>outbound rate: '+this["outbound"]["rate"]+'</td>';
        txt += '</tr>';
        txt += '</tr><tr>';
        txt += '<td>outbound rate: '+this["outbound"]["ip"]["rate"]+'</td>';
        txt += '</tr>';
 etc. etc.
});
});
```

This does not work and I get "undefined". how can I access elements of the returned json in this way?

Many thanks!

Comment: you done the program in very bad way. Firstly you are defining variable in each loop. So each time your txt value will change. Secondly your mapping. I was not able to find this["outbound"]["ip"]["rate"]. This line means you have outbound in which you have ip and in which you have rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each()` loops through each property of the `data` object. Based on how you're explicitly building the HTML, I don't think that's the approach you want to use here.

Below is an example of what I think you're looking for. Note that I've included two examples of how to get to a nested piece of data -- one using brackets, the other using periods.

And here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/92h5gwoz/

```
$.getJSON("/get_pricing_data?iso="+iso, function(data) {
    var txt = '<tr>';
    txt += '<td>country: ' + data["country"] + '</td>';
    txt += '</tr><tr>';
    txt += '<td>outbound rate: ' + data["message"]["outbound"]["rate"] + '</td>';
    txt += '</tr>';
    txt += '</tr><tr>';
    txt += '<td>outbound rate: ' + data.voice.outbound.ip.rate + '</td>';
    txt += '</tr>';
});
```

Comment: @user1903663: honzahommer's answer was posted before mine, and was a valid answer, so his should probably get accepted. But I'll leave mine here since it gives a little bit of explanation that might be helpful to you, and also provides you with a JSFiddle so you can see it in action.

Comment: Here's a fiddle I had worked up before checking back for posted answers: http://jsfiddle.net/n0meepn3/

Comment: scholar and a gentleman, thank you! Previous answer technically correct too but this addresses more closely my needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('/get_pricing_data?iso=' + iso, function(data) {
    console.log(data.country);
    console.log(data.message.inbound.rate);
    console.log(data.message.outbound.rate);
});
```

Comment: both answers correct but I prefer the second as it addreses my needs directly. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @user1903663 this answer will teach you more... doing some logging of values to the browser console would have likely helped you figure things out